# HTML Button is non-responsive, console doesn't register event

Tags: javascript, python, html

Working on a simple to-do app, but having a problem with the delete button.  When I click, the browser console doesn't even register an event.  Super confused on what to do here.  I've gone through all my code in index.html as well as the app.py code, I can't figure out why it's not even registering in the browser that something happened, even if it doesn't lead to what I want it to do.  Basically just not sure how to debug something that's not even registering as existing I guess?

I'm assuming it's a problem in the HTML but just in case, I'm including the relevant python code as well.

Thanks!

index.html

```
<ul id="todos">
            {% for d in data %}
            <li><input class="check-completed" data-id="{{ d.id }}" 
                type="checkbox" {% if d.completed %} checked {% endif %}> {{ d.description }}
                <button class="li button deletebutton" data-id="{{ d.id }}">&cross;</button>  <!-- &cross; is HTML for an X-->
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

script in index.html:

```
const deletebtns = document.querySelectorAll('.deletebutton');
            
            for (let i = 0; i < deletebtns.length; i++) {
                const deletebutton = deletebtns[i];
                deletebutton.onclick = function(e) {
                    const todoId = e.target.dataset['id'];
                    fetch('/todos/' + todoId, {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        })
                    }
                   
                }
            }
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/todos/<todo_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_todo(todo_id):
    try:
        Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).delete()
        db.session.delete(todo)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: where are you referencing your script tag (head or at bottom of body)?, try console logging `deletebtns` to see if buttons are being queried

Comment: try using `getElementsByClassName('deletebutton')`. `querySelectorAll` returns a NON-live collection of elements

Comment: @AngelSalazar Script tag is bottom of body.  The console log doesn't show anything happening at all, its as if nothing is being clicked

Comment: @IgorMoraru no luck, still no response

Comment: ok, try wrapping your code inside this `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { //PASTE YOUR CODE });`

Comment: @AngelSalazar Looks like it was actually an issue of a misplaced } in a totally different section of the code  Having fixed that, I'm now getting a 405 "method not allowed" error when clicking the delete button, and the console highlights the ' fetch('/todos/' + todoId, { ' line.  Any idea why, since the method allowed on the app.py side is still delete?